# Is "Should airbag controlling firmware/software comply to any software engineering standards?" on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the following an on-topic question on Stack Overflow?

> Should airbag controlling firmware/software comply to any software engineering standards (like for example [IEC 62304](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_62304))?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *comply* instead of *complain*? And yes, it would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is there any stackexchange site where it would be on-topic?

Comment: Looks like it would also be off-topic on [mechanics.se] and [electronics.se], so probably not.

Comment: hmm, programmers.se maybe as it's about software development practices, but I seriously doubt it'd be answerable there as it's an extreme niche environment.

Comment: it would be safer to ask at [Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/) prior to posting there. There is a fat chance for such a question to be closed as [unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6819/is-this-question-appropriate-for-the-programmers-stack-exchange#comment18426_6819) at Programmers

Comment: @gnat Can I ask directly this same question at http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ or do I need to ask for a migration of this question?

Comment: ask directly at Prog meta, and keep this question here. That way, you'll get evaluation from perspective of both sites. As opposed to main sites, [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'") between per site metas seems to make good sense :)

Comment: @jwenting Do you have some references to support the statement that *"it's an extreme niche environment"*?

Comment: @uvts_cvs AFAIK there's only 1 or 2 manufacturers of note of airbags, who also supply the software for them. That's not a lot of people, and all those would be well aware of the rules regarding their product. So there's maybe a few dozen (at most a few hundred) people worldwide who have the exact knowledge needed to answer the question, and probably a few dozen more who're interested because they plan to apply for a position at one of those companies. I'd call that an extreme niche :)

Comment: Yes. In the United States it would be regulated by the [National Highway Traffic Safety Administration](http://www.nhtsa.gov/Laws+&+Regulations/Air+Bags). Outside of the United States it would be regulated by various other national bodies. Additionally, per my time at a major electronics manufacturer you could potentially face unlimited damages should your software fail for any reason. Which is why we never entered the market with our product.

Comment: Sounds like a business/legal question to me.  Consult a lawyer.

Comment: This question is off-topic anywhere.  Anyone who needs to know the answer to this question should already know it.  If they don't, then they are not qualified to even be thinking about writing software for this purpose.  This is why we have accredited engineering standards pretty much all over the world.  If you have to ask the internet this question and it is for your job, then you are not qualified to do your job and both you and your employer are in for an enormous world of hurt.